# How to prevent select2 to call select2:close the second time when selectOnClose is set to true?

Tags: jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I am using Select2 V. 4.0.10

I want to have a select2 that behaves the same way when you select using the Enter key and the Tab key.

What happens is that when selecting using the Tab key, the close event is called twice, which is not what was intended to do.

```js
var data = [
    { id: 0, text: 'New' },
    { id: 1, text: 'In Process' },
    { id: 2, text: 'Draft' },
    { id: 3, text: 'Submitted' },
    { id: 4, text: 'Deleted' }
];

$(".test").select2({
    allowClear: true,
    selectOnClose: true,
    data: data,
    placeholder: "Select a status"
});

$("select.test", "body").off("select2:close").on("select2:close", function (e){
    // This is called twice
    console.log("select2:close");
});
```

```css
select.test {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.10/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.10/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<select class="test"></select>
```

Here are the sequences of the select2 events that are triggered when selecting with the Tab/Enter key.

**TAB**

- select2:opening
- select2:open
- select2:closing
- select2:selecting
- change
- change.select
- select2:closing
- select2:close
- select2:select
- select2:close

**ENTER**

- select2:opening
- select2:open
- select2:selecting
- change
- change.select
- select2:closing
- select2:close
- select2:select

Comment: Your solution with a global variable will hit its limits when you have more than one `select2` box to deal with. Yes, you can simply make another global variable, and then another one. But I suppose you can see the inelegance and inflexibility. Using `debounce` is the better approach.

Comment: That being said, solutions are supposed to go to the "answers" section, they are not supposed to be question edits.

Comment: I have edited this as you mentioned and added it as an answer here below. Thank you for the assistance. Just new to this platform

Comment: No worries. If you prefer your solution, you're free to accept it. (Answering your own questions is generally encouraged on SO, there's nothing wrong with it, especially when you share working code.)

Answer (score 0):

As the pattern in always the same, the solution was to create a variable that would be toggled on when select2:select was triggered, and use that to see if it was be used before.
Notice, instead of using the global window object you should rather use a class variable or a prototype property to store this boolean.

```js
var data = [
    { id: 0, text: 'enhancement' },
    { id: 1, text: 'bug' },
    { id: 2, text: 'duplicate' },
    { id: 3, text: 'invalid' },
    { id: 4, text: 'wontfix' }
];

window._select2Select = false;

$(document).on('select2:select', "select", function (e) {
  window._select2Select = true;
});

$(".test").select2({
  allowClear: true,
  selectOnClose: true,
  data: data,
  placeholder: "Select a status"
});

$("select.test", "body")
  .off("select2:close")
  .on("select2:close", function(e) {
    if(window._select2Select){
      window._select2Select = false;
      return;
    }
    console.log("select2:close");
    window._select2Select = false;
  });
```